# sollution for Warning occouring while installing Radium in React app

Tags: reactjs, frontend, warnings, radium

I Actually had tried to install Radium in React app but facing some Warnings as in bellow scren shot

[Screen shot of the warnings i am facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUehv.jpg)

Comment: Post the actual code/text, not pictures of it. There isn't really any "solution" to this issue, radium has some dependencies and based on `npm audit` those dependencies have some potential vulnerabilities. The only real solution is don't use radium, or create your own fork and clean up those vulnerabilities. However, you'll soon find out that everything apart from the most simple packages will have these warnings, and most times you'll just ignore them

Comment: @Jayce444 as the ext is too long i cannot post it over here so posting image was the only option for me to ask my query

Comment: @Jayce444 so what would you sujjest me to do further